# How to remove AWS CodeDeploy bundle.tar from instance after deploy

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I set up CodeDeploy with BitBucket. So I can deploy my latest commits via Bitbucket UI. But every deploy it creates a bundle.tar on instances to this directory `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/` [image: bundle.tar]

I tried to add a hook `AfterInstall`, simple bash script that just finds and removes created bundle but it gives me an error now. Nothing in logs. Here is my appspec.yml file:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html/mysite.com
permissions:
  - object: /var/www/html/mysite.com
    pattern: "**"
    owner: user
    group: www
    mode: 444
    type:
      - file
  - object: /var/www/html/mysite.com
    pattern: "**"
    owner: user
    group: www
    mode: 555
    type:
      - directory
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: /usr/local/scripts/deploy/remove-bundle-after-deploy.sh
    timeout: 180
    runas: root
```

Here is the `remove-bundle-after-deploy.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/ -type f -name bundle.tar -exec rm -f {} +
```

How to set up CodeDeploy to not create bundle.tar files at all on my instances? Is that possible? If not, how can I remove them after successful deploy?

Comment: I know this is not the best solution but I set up cron job to execute my bash file once a day. If some one could help me to find a better solution I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Only last 5 copies are kept on server. Its required by code deploy agent to compare the changes from current files, and/or if any file conflict exists before deploying, as well as in case of rollback, its best to let it be there.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Thank you man! You are the best! I couldn't find any information about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually configure the max revisions you want CodeDeploy to store.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/host-cleanup.html#host-agent-cleanup

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you!